# Wordpress - Modify WooCommerce Germanized Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with WooCommerce including the WooCommerzce Germanized Plugin.
The Plugin changes a lot of WooCommerce to make it safe for usage in Germany.

Now I need to modify a template file of the plugin.  Whats the best way to make the changes? I don't want to modify the template itself to keep it safe for updates.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override *any* WooCommerce plugin template you should create a folder in your active theme named after the plugin you are going to modify. Then follow the template folders structure ignoring just the folder `templates` and copy the desired file there.

For example, I needed to modify the WooCommerce Germanized Pro template based in `/plugins/woocommerce-germanized-pro/templates/checkout/multistep/data.php`. To modify it I have copied it to my theme: `/themename/woocommerce-germanized-pro/checkout/multistep/data.php` -- this way it will override an original template file.

Good luck!